# conditional XML, showing a tag only if the value exists for some other tag

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

before I begin I must confess I am a newbie to XML. I have always consumed it without paying much thought that how they are created in the first place.
So I have a XML document, now based on the value of few tags I need to wither show or hide its children. Do you know how I can do that. I have a feeling that XSL should bw able to handle that. 
But I can test for the value of parent with XSL, but I am not sure how I will hide or show the children using the XSL.
So for example in the below XML (this is how my template also looks like), I want to show the GlobalQHPCosts tag only if UseGlobalQHP is set to Yes.

```
<UseGlobalQHP>No</UseGlobalQHP>
<GlobalQHPCosts>
  <Month>January</Month>
<QHPPrice/>
</GlobalQHPCosts>
```

Comment: Can you add some material as an input? Can you explain what you mean with "*hide or show the children*"? Thanks.

Comment: I just added the changes. Can you provide your feedback now

Comment: You say "show or hide", which assumes activity. Do you mean show/hide in HTML based on a click or other event (requires JavaScript)? Or should the child element be removed from the XML before further processing (the latter case: XSLT can help if you have it set up).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show the GlobalQHPCosts tag only if UseGlobalQHP is set to Yes.

Not sure this is what you are after, but *if* you want to do this with XSLT, it is a trivial exercise:

```
<!-- boilerplate: copies everything not matched elsewhere unaltered -->
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- if UseGlobalQHP is NO, we do not want this element -->
<xsl:template match="GlobalQHPCosts[preceding-sibling::UseGlobalQHP[1][. = 'No']]">
    <!-- do nothing, we want to remove this -->
</xsl:template>
```